# Is this a bug in jQuery Iframe code or expected behaviour?

Tags: jquery, iframe

In jquery the way you access an iframe is

```
$("#myIframe").contents();
```

say you wanted "#myDiv" from "#myIframe", you would use

```
$("#myIframe").contents().find("#myDiv");
```

In some code I've been writing I had this

```
var $SaveQuery = $("#myIframe").contents().find("#myDiv");
var $InnerQuery = $SaveQuery.find("#myInnerDiv");
```

Did not work. Using the debugger I inspected the $SaveQuery object. The innerHtml was always

```
"                         "
```

even when I was looking at it filled with content on my screen.  After much hair pulling I changed it to this and it did work

```
var $SaveQuery = $("#myIframe").contents().find("#myDiv");
var $InnerQuery = $("#myIframe").contents().find("#myInnerDiv");
```

Is this a bug or is this expected behavior? I'm using version 2.2.0

Comment: What about this? `$("#myIframe").contents().find("#myDiv").find("#myInnerDiv")`

Comment: If these two statements: var $query = $("#outer"); $query.find("#inner"); were not equivalent to this $("#outer").find("#inner"); then the fundamental theorem of jquery would be broken. I'm not testing that. It would be such a huge bug. If there's a problem with iframes that's a much smaller bug.